# C++ Array of chars based off of keyboard inputs

Tags: c++

I would like a simple way of just getting an array of chars of keyboard inputs, or some other way of getting keyboard inputs that does not wait for a newline. NCurses or PDCurses looks appealing but as the project I am working on is a one off type of project and I wont be doing a project similar to this I do not want to spend the time learning it full on. The method does not have to be cross platform as I have already committed to using windows.

Comment: Any other approach, including system-specific ones, is likely to be just as complicated as just using curses.

Comment: I'm sorry but due to a policy I didn't agree with, no question asking for recommendation of book or library (or...), I must vote to close this.

Comment: On the bright side, did you know about [this StackExchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` is an array of chars, isn't it?

For inputing without `\n` you can use `conio.h` and `_getch()`

Comment: What i meant for the array part is an array of Boolean's that goes in alphabetical order and is true if the key corresponding to that index of the array is pushed down, conio.h works for what I am doing though.

Comment: What do you mean by _array of **Boolean's** that goes in **alphabetical** order_

Comment: Do you meen you need a one array with char and boolean data? It can be done with class. `class MyClass{ private: std::vector<char> myCharArray; std::vector<bool> myBoolArray; public: MyClass(); ~MyClass(); getCh(int i){return myCharArray[i];}; getBool(int i){return myBoolArray[i]}; putCh(char c){myCharArray.push_back(c);}; putBool(bool b){myBoolArray.push_back(b);} ;}` don't forget `#include <vector>`